How to remove distribution across field in Box plot chart in Apache superset
"When creating a box plot in Apache Superset, there is a field labeled 'Distribution Across' that I need to remove. This field is mandatory, and I cannot put the same values in both the 'Distribution Across' field and the X-axis. When creating the X and Y axes, this field is causing an unwanted split in the data. I tried using a dummy column in that field, but it still isn't working. How can I remove or bypass this field while creating the box plot?"
I need either to remove that filed from advanced chart settings

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
